# How to make google Autofill correct address inputs

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome

[image]
When I click autofill, It only fills the first input. Is there a way to make it autofill, the other inputs. I am using reactjs.

```
<div className={`${styles.formGroup} ${styles.address}`}>
        <label className={styles.label} htmlFor="address">
          Address
        </label>
        <input
          value={address}
          onChange={(e) => setAddress((prev) => e.target.value)}
          className={styles.input}
          type="text"
          id="address"
          name="address"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div className={`${styles.formGroup} ${styles.address}`}>
        <label className={styles.label} htmlFor="address">
          Apartment
        </label>
        <input
          value={apartment}
          onChange={(e) => setApartment((prev) => e.target.value)}
          className={styles.input}
          type="text"
          id="address"
          name="address"
          required
        />
      </div>
        <div className={`${styles.formGroup} `}>
          <label className={styles.label} htmlFor="governorate">
            Governorate
          </label>
          <Select
            options={governorates}
            value={governorate}
            onChange={(e) => setGovernorate((prev) => e)}
            styles={{
              control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
                ...baseStyles,
                borderRadius: "4px",
                padding: "4.6px",
              }),
            }}
          />
        </div>
```

How do I make it so that it automatically fills the other inputs